# Single Child thread notifying Parent to indicate that it is finished so Parent can launch another child [C#]

Tags: c#

I have a PARENT thread responsible for performing jobs, for each job it launches a CHILD thread to do the work - however it should never be allowed to launch more then one at a time (single child). For example in the case where there are 10 jobs to do it should do them one-after-another - therefore the PARENT needs to be know when each job has completed so it can launch the next pending one.

Typically I would just .Join() or a WaitHandle to accomplish this task - except that in this case I cannot block the Parent thread as it has other responsibilites that need to be performed while waiting for the child to complete ...

Allow me to illustrates:

```
class Parent
{

private Thread threadJob;

public Parent()
    {
    // this is where the main loop occurs
    while (bRun)
        {

        // This is where I need help ... how can I know that threadJob is not currently performing a task?
        // is there an event it can fire to let Parent know that it is done? A flag it can set?
        if (threadJob child is not currently running a job)
            {
            threadJob = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PerformWork));
            threadJob.IsBackground = true;
            threadJob.Start();
            }

        .. do other work ...
        .. keep doing other work ...

        }
    }
};
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of handling this is to keep the worker thread alive the whole time and have it read from a queue of pending jobs.  This way, you only do one job at a time, in sequence, but you don't need to worry about synchronizing with the main thread.  The output of the job can go into a queue of its own, which the main thread can check for empty and retrieve from if not.

*edit*

Looking at your example more closely, it doesn't appear that the work the thread does is different each time, so perhaps just have the thread loop instead of terminating.

Comment: Nah - the work can be different each time, perform work does different things depending on various factors - but it is also the same function(PerformWork) called - it just figures it out internally.

The thread needs to terminate...

Comment: @Shaitain00: Why does the thread need to terminate instead of just looping?

Comment: The PARENT thread is responsible for scheduling the task, the calling application will ask the PARENT to do something and then the parent will set certain flags and other things, then launch the child (who will use these flags to perform the task it needs).

I just thought that launching the thread when needed based on requests from the parent was the best approach ...

Comment: Consider if the worker thread waited on an event at the top of a big loop, and the main thread only signaled the event after it had set up the various flags and such.  This would avoid creating and destroying the worker thread.  And if the information that the worker needed was encapsulated in a simple job object, then the parent could schedule items as it learned about the need, rather than trying to synchronize with another thread.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Thread.IsAlive`, if you're happy to effectively poll as shown in the question.

Comment: How does a thread become not IsAlive? Just by terminating or is there something specific I need to do when the thread is finished?

Comment: It's actually a bit trickier than that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive.aspx

Comment: Not sure I see what is "trickier" (unless I am missing something). If the thread completes normally (or worst-case is aborted) then IsAlive will return false (great - I can launch another one), otherwise it will be true (running the task)...

What did I miss? :)

Comment: The comment at the bottom: "If ThreadState is AbortRequested, IsAlive will return true, this can lead to ThreadAbortException."

Comment: @Steven: I'm not sure how it leads to ThreadAbortException (other than the TAE is about to be thrown anyway)... but it's fine for it to count as being alive while the thread is *being* aborted. When the abort has completed, it'll return false... where's the problem?

Comment: @Jon: It's not a problem, just a complication that makes things trickier.

Comment: @Steven: How does it make things trickier really? Unless you really, *really* want to treat "being aborted" as "dead" (in which case it's a simple "or") I'd just leave it - yes, it means you'll have a bit longer with no threads doing active work, but you've always got that pseudo-race-condition.

Comment: @Jon: Like I said, it's not a problem, just a complication.  It means that a thread can say it's alive even though we're in the process of aborting it.  As you say, this is an inevitable race condition, not a bug.  The consequence is that IsAlive is a good way to see if a thread is long dead, but no assurance of its current health.  Does that clarify my initial comment?